# Feedme Plugin: Why won't it give me a pagination URL option?

Tags: plugin-feedme

I have a JSON field that I've setup with the following structure:

```
{
    "pagination_url": "https://myapi.com?pageNumber=2",
    "items: [
        {"thing": "thing", "thing": "thing"},
        {"thing": "thing", "thing": "thing"}
    ]
}
```

When I go to the feed setup screens, where you choose your "Primary Element" everything is fine. It shows that my root has 2 things, but that "items" has more and you can choose "items" as the root element.

But below that where you choose "Pagination URL", there are no options in the drop-down. It won't let me select "pagination_url". It just says "No Pagination URL".

The documentation doesn't say much, but as far as I can tell I'm following the directions. https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/feature-tour/primary-element.html#pagination-url

What am I missing here?

Comment: That should work. Can you [try validating](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) your `JSON`, there might be an error in there.

Comment: Yes, JSON is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround! This does seem like a UI issue for Feedme. When you get to the point in the configuration and it was only presenting me with a dropdown of "No Pagination URL", I inspected the page with browser tools and just created a new option in that form with a value of "pagination_url", made sure it was selected, then proceeded and it worked fine after that!